# Search through a file with all the words in the dictionary

Tags: java

Okay so the question is to read in the file and search through it and be able to find words with the letters you entered so for example I enter `A??C` all the words in the dictionary with A as the first letter and C as the fourth letter would be returned. It is supposed to be used to help solve crosswords

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass reader = new NewClass();
        String[] contents = reader.load("/home/se211012/CS211/text");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter word");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {

        }
    }
}
```

Reading in the file is fine I have a class that does that as you can see, but I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like homework to me. You may want to tag it as such, and declare if you are expected to be familiar with regular expressions (since that would be the method industry programmers would use to solve this in their work)

Comment: sorry this is the first time I used the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to achieve it.

Create your regex to match the words, and search for a match through the collection.

Note that in regular expressions, `.` means any character.

You might want to hava a look on the [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) classes as well.

Comment: Okay so now I have this and it won't print. I entered regex when it asks me to enter a word

String s= scan.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i< contents.length; i++){
    if(scan.nextLine().matches(contents[i]))
         System.out.println(contents[i]);

Comment: @user1244808: Note that `matcher()` asks for an **exact match** so `"abcde".matches("a..d") == false`. However, `"abcde".matches("a..d.*") == true`. I doubt I can give more useful advises without additional information on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider to convert the search criteria into regex. for example:

```
A??C -> A[A-Z]{2}C or A\w{2}C or whatever you need for the ? placeholder
```

then search the dictionary with the regex.